# How to add bathymetry values as shade under matplolib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have created a cross-section plot from a pivot table containing latitude as columns, depth as index, and oxygen concentrations as values.

```
depth2 = pivot_df.index
lati2 = pivot_df.columns
oxygen2 = pivot_df.values.transpose()
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(lati2,depth2,indexing='ij')
#from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
levels = np.linspace(240, 400)
plt.contourf(xi,yi,oxygen2, cmap = 'jet', levels=levels,vmin=240, vmax=400)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
cbar = plt.colorbar(extend ='both')
cbar.set_label('Dissolved Oxygen Concentrations (umol/kg)', fontsize=18)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Latitude',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Pressure (dbar)' ,fontsize=18)
plt.ylim(bottom = 1000)
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)
plt.plot(lati2,range(len(lati2)), 'gD',clip_on=False, markersize=10, zorder=20)#This plot each latitude point where measurements were took. 

plt.title("DISSOLVED OXYGEN CONCENTRATIONS: NORTHERN CANADA BASIN", pad=30, fontsize=18)
```

The following plot is the result, and I am happy with it, but I would like to add bathymetry values from ETOPO files and plot them as a shaded area under my plot.

[image]

So far, I have this

## bathymetry

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset

data = Dataset("ETOPO1_Bed_g_gmt4.grd",'r')

lon_range = data.variables['x'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z'][:]
```

But,  I would like to plot the regions, using my latitude, longitude values from my dataset, extract them from the ETOPO files, and plot them similar to what we can do using Ocean Data view, an example below:
[image]

I am unsure how to proceed with this cross-section profile and how I can easily add the bathymetry values to my plot.